# Is it possible to mirror/duplicate UDP traffic using envoy?

Tags: rproxy

I have a use case where the incoming UDP data has to be sent to multiple environments simultaneously.
I am currently trying with Envoy. I see that envoy has something called `request_mirror_policies'` but when I use it in my config I get the error  `exiting Protobuf message (type envoy.config.bootstrap.v3.Bootstrap reason INVALID_ARGUMENT: invalid JSON in envoy.config.bootstrap.v3.Bootstrap   @ static_resources.listeners[0].listener_filters[0].typed_config.<any>.matcher.on_no_match.action.typed_config.<any>:  message envoy.extensions.filters.udp.udp_proxy.v3.Route,  near 1:337 (offset 336): no such field:  'request_mirror_policies') has unknown fields`

This is my entire envoy config.yaml

````
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        protocol: UDP
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 4445
    listener_filters:
    - name: envoy.filters.udp_listener.udp_proxy
      typed_config:
        '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.udp.udp_proxy.v3.UdpProxyConfig
        stat_prefix: service
        matcher:
          on_no_match:
            action:
              name: route
              typed_config:
                '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.udp.udp_proxy.v3.Route
                cluster: service_udp
                request_mirror_policies:
                  cluster: service_udp_two
                  runtime_fraction: 
                    default_value:
                      numerator: 50
                      denominator: HUNDRED
  clusters:
  - name: service_udp
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service_udp
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: k8s-test-nkln-jkl-o8u8ouij.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
                port_value: 4445
  - name: service_udp_two
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service_udp_two
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: k8s-asdasd-udpliste-asd-asdasd.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
                port_value: 4445
admin:
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 10001
    ```
````